# Casting date to int

Tags: mysql, datetime, casting, integer

Please help me get past this:

In MySQL, why does this work:

```sql
CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(`STG_users`.`lastlogindate`/1000,'%Y%m%d') AS UNSIGNED)
```

(where `STG_users.lastlogindate` is a `BIGINT`)

When this does not:

```sql
CAST(DATE_FORMAT(`Login_Activity_Temp`.`timestamp`,'%Y%m%d') AS UNSIGNED)
```

(where `Login_Activity_Temp.timestamp` is a `DATETIME`)

I need the last one (or something similar) to work.

--- UPDATED ---

I does work!!!
(Thanks all)

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What do you mean it "does not work"?  Can you show us with explicit data, what results you get, and what you expect to see?

Comment: Thanks pilcrow, rewriting the query in a another tool (MySQL Workbench) got it to run through! Now it's error solving in the original tool (Talend)

Answer (score 1):

DATE_FORMAT returns the date formated into a string..

CAST(Login_Activity_Temp.timestamp AS UNSIGNED)

Should do it, no need to convert into a string.

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME, as the OP is using it, also returns a string.  Something else is amiss.

Comment: Nice! Except i need only the date in this one, and not include the time. And as an extension of this I need to do the same for time.

date(int)=20120416
time(int)=1734